# Custom tag doesn't allow for wildcard based tags in new navigation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

The new navigation doesn't seem to accept wildcards, in this specific case an asterisk when entering the tag. If I enter an `*` after the tag name, it gets stripped